# Which test of statistical significance for 2 variables (categorical data), but with more than 2 categories on one of the variables?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data

So I'm working on a project, one aspect of which looks at the effect of nationality (my independent variable) on the tendency to quit a job (my dependent variable) and I can't figure out which test to use.

I know if it was two categorical variables each with only two categories (e.g., the effect of sex on tendency to quit) I could use a chi-square test. And I think I'm right in saying if I was working with one categorical variable with more than 2 categories and one scale variable (e.g., the effect of nationality on IQ) I could use simple ANOVA, but my knowledge of stats isn't advanced enough to know what to do in these circumstances.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The chi-square test works just fine with more than two categories--in fact it works for arbitrary two-dimensional contingency tables. For instance [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence) gives the general formula for the statistic and you can find [examples of doing this in R](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/goodness-fit/chi-squared-test-independence), etc. Just be sure you meet the [frequency assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Assumptions), which can be difficult if you have too many categories compared to your sample size.